# Inserting items of second viewcontroller values to the table When a navigation button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am Having `Tableview` as my `mainViewcontroller` and added button in the `Navigation Bar`.

When a button is clicked,it pushes to second viewController(`UIViewController`) and it prompts the user to enter a value that to be inserted in the Table..

Can anyone help me to do this? **Im doing in cocoa Touch (iphone)**

Comment: Im new to iphone.. can u tell me the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in AppDelegate.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *string;
```

Write this code in AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize string;
```

When you will go second view give string to AppDelegate class instance.

```
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate

 appDelegate.string = [textField text];
```

When you come back on main view controller you need reload data of table view you write this code into ViewWillAppear method.

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate

[tableArray addObject:appDelegate.string];
[tableName reloadData];
```

Comment: I am not able to use @synthesize in appDelegate.h as it throws error:synthesized property 'b' must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar... can you suggest some more?

Comment: "b" is nothing but variable for the NSString

Comment: can you  show me you code.now i will reply you within 3 hours

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 NSLog(@"beforevwa");
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 tabletrials1AppDelegate *appDelegate = (tabletrials1AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
 [array insertObject:appDelegate.s1 atIndex:[array count]];
 
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 NSLog(@"after viewwillappear");

Comment: Actually i am trying to insert the entered items from second viewcontroller to the array(which is declared in firstview i.e tableview).. i need those newly entered items to be added.

Comment: i have some values in array previously to show up in the table cell.. i have a doubt. after returning to the firstview(Tableview) which method will be called.. because i need to store the values of entered items.. Im not getting wen i tried to write in viewwillappear method

Comment: In view willAppear you are write [super viewDidAppear:animated]; it is wrong please replies it with [super viewWillAppear:animated];

Comment: S i get the second viewcontroller values in first view.. but its not getting inserted.. May i know when (self.editing) can be used?

Comment: - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}

Comment: after this i need to insert the values in an array .. and then from array to table cell.. Where do i need to insert the code?

Comment: if(array!=nil)
 {
 
 for(int j=0;j<[acontroller.addedarray count];j++)
   {
   NSLog(@"%@",acontroller.addedarray);
   [array insertObject:[acontroller.addedarray objectAtIndex:j] atIndex:[array count]];
  }
 }
 else
 {
  array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:acontroller.addedarray];

 }
 NSLog(@"Array now %@",array);
 //
 [self.tableView reloadData];
 

 NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear"); 
 }

Comment: Thanks Hardeep i found the answer... i showed up above.. I understood the purpose of delegate though i not used it

Comment: i'm not reply  you so i'm really  sorry for that.

Comment: Your welcome.... Pls join my chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15676/iosroom